# Open 2 Crystal Reports together in PDF with parameter

Tags: c#, pdf, mvvm, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports.
I made 2 reports that i want to open together in PDF.

I want just the reports that have a certain ID.
Atm only "Containerlijst" gives a report with the ID,
but it shows "PersAfdruk" and PersAfdruk shows all ID's of "PersAfdruk".

With the code i got i open the same report 2 times.
But with the different names i gave.
Using MVVM and this code is in my Command.

```
 try
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

            ReportDocument PersAfdruk = new ReportDocument();
            ReportDocument Containerlijst = new ReportDocument();
            PersAfdruk.Load("../../Persorderlijst.rpt");
            PersAfdruk.SetParameterValue("PersOrderID", txtPersOrderID);
            Containerlijst.Load("../../Containerlijst.rpt");
            Containerlijst.SetParameterValue("PersOrderID", txtPersOrderID);

            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDes = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormat = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            CrDiskFileDes.DiskFileName = "d:\\Persorderlijst.pdf";
            CrDiskFileDes.DiskFileName = "d:\\Containerlijst.pdf";
            CrExportOptions = PersAfdruk.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDes;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatOptions = CrFormat;
            }
            PersAfdruk.Export();
            Process.Start("d:\\Persorderlijst.pdf");
            Process.Start("d:\\Containerlijst.pdf");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the elegant way to do this but it works for me.
Feedback welcome.

```
 try
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

            ReportDocument PersAfdruk = new ReportDocument();
            ReportDocument Containerlijst = new ReportDocument();
            PersAfdruk.Load("../../Persorderlijst.rpt");
            PersAfdruk.SetParameterValue("PersOrderID", txtPersOrderID);
            Containerlijst.Load("../../Containerlijst.rpt");
            Containerlijst.SetParameterValue("PersOrderID", txtPersOrderID);

            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            ExportOptions CrExportOptions1;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDes = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDes1 = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormat = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormat1 = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            CrDiskFileDes.DiskFileName = "d:\\Persorderlijst.pdf";
            CrDiskFileDes1.DiskFileName = "d:\\Containerlijst.pdf";
            CrExportOptions = PersAfdruk.ExportOptions;

            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDes;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatOptions = CrFormat;
            }
            CrExportOptions1 = Containerlijst.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions1.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions1.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions1.ExportDestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDes1;
                CrExportOptions1.ExportFormatOptions = CrFormat1;
            }
            PersAfdruk.Export();
            Containerlijst.Export();

            Process.Start("d:\\Persorderlijst.pdf");
            Process.Start("d:\\Containerlijst.pdf");

        }
```